# JSON - parsing document with JSONArray in Java

Tags: java, json, arrays, simplejson

I'm parsing this document:
http://pastebin.com/M3Gsbf1t
as you can see it's kind of big. This document was generated by Youtube Data API v3.
I want to get all "title" elements and display them.
My code:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(str); // str contains the JSON code
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;               
JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("title");
Iterator iterator = msg.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

but it returns "NullPointerException".
If I replace the "title" with the "items" it works fine but it returns me a lot of informations that I don't need. 
I'm using the JSON.simple library.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: `title` is not at the root of the JSON. You need to traverse the JSON object tree to get it. Also, where is `title` a `JSONArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;               
    JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");
    Iterator iterator = msg.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      //System.out.println(iterator.next());
      JSONObject item = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
      JSONObject item_snippet = (JSONObject) item.get("snippet");
      System.out.println( item_snippet.get("title"));
    }
```

You have a JSONObject at the root of your JSON string. In it, there's an JSONArray named `items`. From it you have to pull out individual items in while loop.

For each item there's JSONObject `snippet` nested in. Finally you'll find your `title` string in it.

Answer (score 0):

jquery solution, this should give you an array of titles unless I am reading the object wrong.

```
  titles = [];
  obj = $.parseJSON(str);
  $.each(obj.items,function(i,v{
     titles.push(v.snippet.title);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(str); // str contains the JSON code
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;               
JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");
Iterator iterator = msg.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  // cast next item to JSONObject
  JSONObject item = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
  // grab the title
  System.out.println(item.get("title"));
}
```